How i can set product count showing per view port/screen on product detail page for cross selling slider in shopware 6.6?
On product detail page, under cross selling slider showing in tabs,
how to set items sort of configuration.
I can see max products to show under back office but could not answer, i'm looking for on count to specifiy desktop/mobile.
cross-selling template (src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/page/product-detail/cross-selling.html.twig) code does not help.
Looking for configuration of this snippet in back office or overriding template is the last way.
https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/trunk/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/element/cms-element-product-slider.html.twig#L18-L28 but this seems global file to me rather than cross selling slider specific only.
Based on link - https://ganlanyuan.github.io/tiny-slider/#responsive-options
    items: 1,
    responsive: {
      640: {
        edgePadding: 20,
        gutter: 20,
        items: 2
      },
      700: {
        gutter: 30
      },
      900: {
        items: 3
      }
    }


Regarding cross-selling at the back office, the "dynamic product groups" type already supports the maximum amount and the Sort Configuration by default, including Price, Name, and Release Date.
If you want to set custom total products per tab cross-selling, you can custom template:
Resources/views/storefront/element/cms-element-cross-selling.html.twig at block cms_element_cross_selling_tabs_content to show {{ products|length }}
Finally, it may be necessary to empty the shop cache to see it apply:
php bin/console cache:clear

